# Is there any option to persist the data in web server (using cache) until iisreset/recycle?

Tags: c#

I want to be stored some master data in web server Cache and that data should not be expired. Consider a master data like type of users -> Trader, Supplier, Producer and so on. So this type of master data is usually less intensive to add/delete/update. Now in a normal scenario the process of querying the database for each request is not cost-effective in terms of server resources, hence it is much better to cache or persist the data. So in this case what type of expiration cache need to be used? Is there any option in cache to persist the data alive in webserver until iisreset/recycle?

Answer (score 0):

gayathri, you can explicitly save the value in cache like below:

```
Cache["UserType"]="Trader";//or any runtime value
```

Regards,
Aamir

Comment: Thanks Aamir, But I want to be stored the data in same entity type. Say for example,  I'll be stored the list of employees data and return type would be  with same return type ie (return type of Employees). Since I've to do some filter logic from the cache result. So it would be better to store and get with same return type.

Comment: about cache expiration, can we use the below approach                         
 To add an item to the data cache with no time-based expiry, use the System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration and System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration values as input parameters

Comment: To your second comment, my reply is "In absolute expiration,data expires after specific time that you set whether the data is accessed or not. While in sliding expiration it expires if cache is not accessed within specific time.". Now to your first comment, if u want to store list of employees, use List class to store employees in cache. Like, make a class of Employees with a couple of properties, like id,name. Then do as follows. Bracket contains code for you to follow.. (List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();  emp.Add(new Employee() {Name="gayathri", Id=1234}); Cache["UserType"]=emp;